# User Interface, fully generated by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I'm trying to find a way to make better UI's.

I was looking an **extJs** demo and it looks very impressive: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html

But I'm not sure if I can use it in a commercial project that will not be distributed, only used to serve pages.

**Do you know any other UI js framework of this kind?**

Is there any other kind of framework I should look into?

Comment: Nice! and its faster than Windows Vista

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna have a look at jQuery / jQuery Ui. They are both distibuted unter the MIT and GPL license (http://jquery.org/license)

jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page
jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

There is also a "Desktop" Interface using both of them http://desktop.sonspring.com/. The project is called "jQuery Desktop" and can be found on gitHub (https://github.com/nathansmith/jquery-desktop/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the license: http://www.sencha.com/products/license.php

Answer (score 0):

Dojo has a bunch of widgets as well.  It depends on how much you are looking for.  jQuery is not as much of a toolkit as it is a library.